# wampserver -- Links are broken on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, css, content-management-system, wamp

I am currently developing a very simple cms using wampserver and I'm planning to upload it to my reserverd server once it's done.
the other day when I was debugging my code through the remote server i got my page loaded without any style or image. I reviewed and simply deleted some '/' and that worked just fine.
For example I changed URLs like this:
before change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"/>
```

After change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
```

When I applied these new URLs to my local project, once again I faced pages without styles or images or js or whatever...what should I do?

Comment: Did you set `base url` in your html?

Comment: Are you visiting a actual URL IE `localhost:8080` or are you accessing it directly IE `C:\My\Directory\To\Website\index.html` ?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour nope.

Comment: @Zak of course i'm not writing the whole url from the beginning. just like is mentioned before.

Comment: I dont mean what are you putting in your `<link>` tag .. I mean .. How are you visiting your home page in your browser?

Comment: @Zak 127.1.0.1/home   ;; this refers to index.php, rewrited in htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the `/` you changed it to relative paths.

So you must now think about your path structure.

For example, if the project was placed in a folder, so the root is: `http://localhost/mycms/` then you go to `./mycms/cats` the relative path to your CSS would be translated to: `./mycms/cats/css/styles.css` which would break it.

You should look into using absolute paths to assets. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//localhost/mycms/css/styles.css"/>
```

This can be achieved by defining or detecting the current URL path from `$_SERVER` variables and prepending your hostname.

So something like which stores in a constant which you can then use throughout your code which will result in the correct absolute path to the webroot:

```
<?php
define('SITE_URL', rtrim(sprintf(
    '%s://%s/%s',
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "443"  ? 'https' : 'http',
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    trim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/')
), '/'));

echo SITE_URL;
```

Then just echo that in your templates.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= SITE_URL ?>/css/styles.css"/>
```